# Pandas pipe throws error that df to be passed as an argument

Tags: python, pandas, pipe

**Pandas pipe throws error that df to be passed as argument**

Ideally pipe should take the dataframe as argument by default which is not happening in my case.

```
class Summary:
def get_src_base_df(self):
    <do stuff>
    return df
    
@staticmethod
def sum_agg(df):
    cols = 'FREQUENCY_ID|^FLAG_'
    df = (df.filter(regex=cols).fillna(0)
          .groupby('FREQUENCY_ID').agg(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum()))
    return df

# few other @static methods

def get_src_df(self):
    df = self.get_src_base_df().pipe(self.sum_agg()) #pipe chain continues  
    # --> error: sum_agg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'
    # but the below line works
    # df = self.get_src_base_df().pipe((lambda x: self.sum_agg(x))) #pipe chain continues
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `self.sum_agg()`, you're calling the `sum_agg` function (`@staticmethod`s in Python are pretty much indistinguishable from functions), and since it doesn't have an argument right there in that call, it rightfully fails. You need to pass the function **object**, not the **value returned by the function**.

Do this, instead :

```py
def get_src_df(self):
    df = self.get_src_base_df().pipe(self.sum_agg)  # note: no parentheses
```

Comment: so within pipe, the functions that require no args doesn't need parenthesis for fun call?
btw you made my day :)

Comment: what if the function  has a col argument  say `def sum_agg(df, col):` In such case should we need to pass df as an argument?

Comment: To answer your first comment - the moment you add a parenthesis to the function within the `pipe` call, you're no longer passing a function, you're passing a dataframe (or, more likely, raising an exception on missing argument :D). If you need to pass another argument to the function, well, take a look at the [pipe docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to see how to do that :)